# Displaying specific Data from different table in table view using python

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to show for selected data in SQL code completely in a table model

```
def display_user_table(self):
        header = ['Pupil Id','First Name','Last Name','Year Level','Plate Number', 'Car Brand', 'Car Colour' ]
    data = show_pupil_table()
    self.table_model = MyTableModel(self, data, header)
    self.tableView.setModel(self.table_model)
    self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.tableView.resizeRowsToContents()
    self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```

Under this is my code for showing the data in the table model

```
def show_pupil_table():
    with ConnectionPool() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('''SELECT pupil_first_name, pupil_last_name, year_level,plate_number, car_brand,car_colour
FROM pupil_info
JOIN family_pupil fp on pupil_info.pupil_id = fp.pupil_id
JOIN family_car fc on fp.family_id = fc.family_id
JOIN car_info ci on fc.car_id = ci.car_id;''')
        return cursor.fetchall()
```

but it only shows this

[image: my output]

my ideal output is to be this

[Ideal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqvJD.png)

Comment: Try to describe what is your expected ouput and what is the actual output (instead of linking an image).
Also, you can try to work out a more minimal example - for instance, use "static" data (a list of test data, instead of the SQL query) to keep the "moving parts" to a minimum.

Comment: 1) explain your question better, 2) provide a [mre], 3) also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: my expected output is to be this " Pupil Id','First Name','Last Name','Year Level','Plate Number', 'Car Brand', 'Car Colour'" but for some reason it doesn't show.